# I have a PCAP file with SIP/RTP... can I replay it into a switch to test compatibility?

Tags: sip, voip, pcap

I have a PCAP file from a system with SIP setup/teardown and RTP. Can I use the PCAP file to test that the compatibility of that switch with mine, by firing the packets into my switch?

If yes, how?

I have seen TCP replay, but I'm not used to it. Can I use Star Trinity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use SIPP tool for testing the switch. Added pcap file into xml file and trigger.

http://sipp.sourceforge.net/doc/reference.html#UAC+with+media